# Fragmented questions

Tags: grammar

How should the following sentence be punctuated:

> If it's not raining, where should we go? The lake? The beach?

I ask because the last two questions are fragments.

Comment: There are a number of options, but it is perfectly fine as is.

Comment: As it stands, it's a sentence plus two fragments, not 'a sentence'.

Comment: Correct, Edwin. My mistake.

Comment: Why would you change what you already have there?  Some dumb rules book?

Comment: I'd argue that each of those fragments actually embodies an implied "Should we go to [...]?"

Answer (score 2):

You can say this:

> If it is raining, where should we go? The lake or the beach?

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed perfectly fine as is.

An alternative among a number of other options would be to say:

> If it's not raining, where should we go? The lake *or* the beach?

Answer (score 0):

As RegDwigнt says, the original wording is correct as is. Another way to preserve the open-endedness of the lake and beach suggestions (which you lose when you reframe the question as an either/or proposition) is to punctuate the sentence like this:

> If it's not raining, where should we go—the lake? The beach?

I have also seen sentences of this type in which the first word after the first question mark is rendered in lowercase, perhaps to emphasize the parallelism between the two options:

> If it's not raining, where should we go—the lake? the beach?

The effect is both comprehensible and appealing, I think.

Comment: I sort of like the later. Though I'm surprised that the dash would be consider appropriate syntax there. What about a colon?

Comment: A colon works fine. Interpreting the nuances of different punctuation marks may be an exercise in subjectivity at its finest—but to me a colon suggests "here are the choices" (albeit expressed with some indecision, thanks to the question marks), while an em dash suggests a break from the initial question "where should we go?" to a musing consideration of two possibilities that just occurred to the speaker (with the further sense that they are not by any means exhaustive). But the colon works, too, and I'm sure that some writers would prefer it here.